# Posting Videos on Facebook using own buttons, similar to share button

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working with facebook integration (API) and stuff and I was wondering if it is possible to post videos on facebook using something similar to the Share button.

I know the share button is depreciated, but it still works... but it pops out a dialog box. I'm trying to figure out how to do something like the share button but not have a popout?

I currently have an input field that I can publish to my facebook stream, but would like to see if I can say upload a video with that input field and click on my own created button and publish on the facebook stream?

Does this question make sense?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I guess something like instagram app and the likes where if you post something to their own streaming, on facebook it'll show a photo too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 choices.

1. If you want to actually upload the video to Facebook you may upload it using the PHP graph API, see this link: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/
2. Publish a feed to the user wall with data regarding the video.
   You can do this by pushing a post request to me/feed and fill in the picture parameter with the thumbnail of the video and a link to it.
   see: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ - under posts - create